# Mysterious behaviour of closure inside a constructor

Tags: javascript

Consider the below code,

```
function Test(){
  var a = 'prabhu';
  Test.prototype.print = function (){ alert(a); a=10; }
}
```

And i am creating object instances for Test,

```
var x = new Test();
var y = new Test();
```

Now accessing the `print` method of the both which is available in their prototype,

```
x.print() //"prabhu"  ok!!
x.print() //10  Double ok!!
```

But

```
y.print() //10  what the?? It should be prabhu. Isn't it?
```

How this is happening? Because while creating the `y` instance, the `constructor` will be called and it will override the `print` function in its prototype. And it will create a `closure` for `a` with value `"prabhu"`. So while accessing it via `print()` it should print `"prabhu"` right? Why is this not happening? A step by step explanation on this behaviour would be really helpful.

**P.S:** I know the behaviour the code if we use `this.a` everywhere instead of `a` and `var a`. So kindly please don't suggest using that. I struggling to figure out why the above explained behaviour is happening.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Never assign functions to the `prototype` object on a constructor function from *within* the constructor, it sets up this crosstalk.

The reason is that the object created via `new Test` has a **live link** to its prototype, not a copy of it. That means if you modify the prototype object, the next time the object looks something up on it (like `print`), it sees the new one. This is a Good Thing™, but it does mean you shouldn't assign to `Test.prototype` from within `Test`.

You're seeing what you're seeing because when you do `var y = new Test()`, you're changing the prototype that the existing `x` uses, chaning its `print` function so it closes over the `a` from that second call (the one that created `y`), not the first one. So if you call `x.print()` after you do that, the `a` that gets updated is the second one, not the first.

Let's follow your code through:

```
function Test(){
  var a = 'prabhu';
  Test.prototype.print = function (){ alert(a); a=10; }
}

var x = new Test();
```

At this point, we have this in memory (leaving off some irrelevant details):

```
    +---------------+   
x-->|   (object)    |   
    +---------------+     +----------+     
    | [[Prototype]] |---->| (object) |     
    +---------------+     +----------+   +-----------------+   
                          | print    |-->| (function)      |   
                          +----------+   +-----------------+   +---------------+
                                         | env             |-->| Environment 1 |
                                         | alert(a); a=10; |   +---------------+
                                         +-----------------+   | a: 'prabhu'   |                
                                                               +---------------+
```

Now we do this:

```
var y = new Test();
```

Now we have:

```
                                         +-----------------+   +---------------+
    +---------------+                    | (function)      |   | Environment 1 |
x-->|   (object)    |                    +-----------------+   +---------------+
    +---------------+                    | env             |-->| a: 'prabhu'   |
    | [[Prototype]] |--+                 | alert(a); a=10; |   +---------------+
    +---------------+  |                 +-----------------+                    
                       |
                       |  +----------+   +-----------------+   +---------------+
                       +->| (object) |   | (function)      |   | Environment 2 |
                       |  +----------+   +-----------------+   +---------------+
                       |  | print    |-->| env             |-->| a: 'prabhu'   |
                       |  +----------+   | alert(a); a=10; |   +---------------+
                       |                 +-----------------+
    +---------------+  |
y-->|   (object)    |  |
    +---------------+  |
    | [[Prototype]] |--+
    +---------------+
```

Note that the old `print` function is no longer connected to the object `x` refers to in any way; it's been replaced with the new one, which refers to the *new* environment created by calling `Test` a second time.
The old function and the environment it used to close over are both eligible for garbage collection now.

Then:

```
x.print() //"prabhu"  ok!!
```

Gives us *(I've left the garbage for now; maybe it was collected, maybe not, doesn't matter)*:

```
                                         +-----------------+   +---------------+
    +---------------+                    | (function)      |   | Environment 1 |
x-->|   (object)    |                    +-----------------+   +---------------+
    +---------------+                    | env             |-->| a: 'prabhu'   |
    | [[Prototype]] |--+                 | alert(a); a=10; |   +---------------+
    +---------------+  |                 +-----------------+                    
                       |
                       |  +----------+   +-----------------+   +---------------+
                       +->| (object) |   | (function)      |   | Environment 2 |
                       |  +----------+   +-----------------+   +---------------+
                       |  | print    |-->| env             |-->| a: 10         |
                       |  +----------+   | alert(a); a=10; |   +---------------+
                       |                 +-----------------+
    +---------------+  |
y-->|   (object)    |  |
    +---------------+  |
    | [[Prototype]] |--+
    +---------------+
```

Note that the call changed the `a` from the *second* call to `Test` (the one that created `y`), not the first one (the garbage).

Then:

```
x.print() //10  Double ok!!
```

Doesn't change anything.

Finally:

```
y.print() //10  what the?? It should be prabhu. Isn't it?
```

Shows 10 for exactly the same reason `x.print()` shows 10: The `print` function is using the `a` from the *second* call to `Test`, not the first one.

Comment: Thanks for your time answering this. But while calling `new Test` for `y`, The `print` function will take new variable `a` which is having value `"prabhu"` as its closure. I having a doubt over there. How it is referring the older updated variable `a`? Can you explain it by quoting my code example?

Comment: *"But while calling `new Test` for `y`, The `print` function will take new variable `a` which is having value "prabhu" as its closure."* The value isn't the closure, but yes, that's what's happening. *"How it is referring the older updated variable a?"* It isn't, the object that both `x` and `y` use as their prototype now has `print` closing over the environment of the *second* call to `Test` (the one that created `y`). `x.print()`, if called after `var y = new Test()`, modifies the second `a`, not the first one. I've added some ASCII-art and further details, hope that helps.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Wow!!! Your diagram explained what I was expecting. Surely will give you a bounty for this whenever that is applicable. Thanks for your valuable time investing in this. :)