# Strange `bind` behavior

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to make a function which is similar to React's `createClass` function. It should take a POJO and turn it into constructor function which can be invoked with additional arguments.

Here's the code:

```
function createClass(obj) {
  return function(args = {}) {
    Object.keys(obj).forEach(k => this[k] = obj[k]);
    Object.keys(args).forEach(k => this[k] = args[k]);
    Object.keys(this.actions).forEach(k => this.actions[k] = this.actions[k].bind(this));
    console.log('binded to', this);
  }
}

const MyClass = createClass({
  actions: {
    foo: function() {
      console.log('actions.foo');
      this.request();
    }
  },
  foo: function() {
    console.log('foo');
    this.request();
  }
});

const req1 = function() {
  console.log('req1 called')
}

const req2 = function() {
  console.log('req2 called')
}

const c1 = new MyClass({request: req1});
const c2 = new MyClass({request: req2});

// As expected
c1.request();
c2.request();
console.log('---')

// As expected
c1.foo();
c2.foo();
console.log('---')

// Error: both call req1
c1.actions.foo();
c2.actions.foo();
console.log('---')
```

I don get why calling `c2.foo()` works as expected, but calling `c2.actions.foo()` instead calls method from another instance. How can it be possible?

Also, [there is jsbin example](http://jsbin.com/beverah/edit?js,console)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because on this line:

```
Object.keys(obj).forEach(k => this[k] = obj[k]);
```

...you're copying `actions` (the reference, not the array) to the new object. Later you update the *contents* of that array, but they're all sharing the same one. Since you're calling `bind` on the functions in `action`, the **first** time they'll get bound to that first instance; subsequently, they won't, because the whole point of `bind` is that it ignores the `this` you call it with, so calling `bind` on a bound function doesn't do anything (with regard to `this`). E.g.:

```
var f = function() { console.log(this.name); };
var f1 = f.bind({name: "first"});
f1();                                                         // "first"
var f2 = f1.bind({name: "second"});
//       ^^------ Note we're using an already-bound function
f2();                                                         // Also "first"
```

Consequently, any call to functions via `actions` will always call those functions with `this` referring to the **first** instance you created.

Solution: Copy the array contents (at least a shallow copy), for instance with `Object.assign`.

Here's that code with some tests removed but checking `c1.actions === c2.actions`, showing that it's `true` (they're using the same array):

```js
function createClass(obj) {
  return function(args = {}) {
    Object.keys(obj).forEach(k => this[k] = obj[k]);
    Object.keys(args).forEach(k => this[k] = args[k]);
    Object.keys(this.actions).forEach(k => this.actions[k] = this.actions[k].bind(this));
    //console.log('binded to', this);
  }
}

const MyClass = createClass({
  actions: {
    foo: function() {
      //console.log('actions.foo');
      this.request();
    }
  },
  foo: function() {
    //console.log('foo');
    this.request();
  }
});

const req1 = function() {
  console.log('req1 called')
}

const req2 = function() {
  console.log('req2 called')
}

const c1 = new MyClass({request: req1});
const c2 = new MyClass({request: req2});

console.log(c1.actions === c2.actions); // true
```

Here's the code making a copy of `actions` first:

```
function createClass(obj) {
  return function(args = {}) {
    Object.keys(obj).forEach(k => {
      if (k === "actions") {
        this[k] = Object.assign({}, obj[k]);
      } else {
        this[k] = obj[k];
      }
    });
    Object.keys(args).forEach(k => this[k] = args[k]);
    Object.keys(this.actions).forEach(k => this.actions[k] = this.actions[k].bind(this));
    //console.log('binded to', this);
  }
}
```

Example:

```js
function createClass(obj) {
  return function(args = {}) {
    Object.keys(obj).forEach(k => {
      if (k === "actions") {
        this[k] = Object.assign({}, obj[k]);
      } else {
        this[k] = obj[k];
      }
    });
    Object.keys(args).forEach(k => this[k] = args[k]);
    Object.keys(this.actions).forEach(k => this.actions[k] = this.actions[k].bind(this));
    //console.log('binded to', this);
  }
}

const MyClass = createClass({
  actions: {
    foo: function() {
      console.log('actions.foo');
      this.request();
    }
  },
  foo: function() {
    console.log('foo');
    this.request();
  }
});

const req1 = function() {
  console.log('req1 called')
}

const req2 = function() {
  console.log('req2 called')
}

const c1 = new MyClass({request: req1});
const c2 = new MyClass({request: req2});

// As expected
c1.request();
c2.request();
console.log('---');

// As expected
c1.foo();
c2.foo();
console.log('---');

// Error: both call req1
c1.actions.foo();
c2.actions.foo();
console.log('---');
```

Or you could generalize and always copy non-function objects:

```
function createClass(obj) {
  return function(args = {}) {
    Object.keys(obj).forEach(k => {
      const src = obj[k];
      if (Array.isArray(src)) {
        this[k] = src.slice();
      } else if (typeof src === "object") {
        this[k] = Object.assign({}, src);
      } else {
        this[k] = src;
      }
    });
    Object.keys(args).forEach(k => this[k] = args[k]);
    Object.keys(this.actions).forEach(k => this.actions[k] = this.actions[k].bind(this));
    //console.log('binded to', this);
  }
}
```

Example:

```js
function createClass(obj) {
  return function(args = {}) {
    Object.keys(obj).forEach(k => {
      const src = obj[k];
      if (Array.isArray(src)) {
        this[k] = src.slice();
      } else if (typeof src === "object") {
        this[k] = Object.assign({}, src);
      } else {
        this[k] = src;
      }
    });
    Object.keys(args).forEach(k => this[k] = args[k]);
    Object.keys(this.actions).forEach(k => this.actions[k] = this.actions[k].bind(this));
    //console.log('binded to', this);
  }
}

const MyClass = createClass({
  actions: {
    foo: function() {
      console.log('actions.foo');
      this.request();
    }
  },
  foo: function() {
    console.log('foo');
    this.request();
  }
});

const req1 = function() {
  console.log('req1 called')
}

const req2 = function() {
  console.log('req2 called')
}

const c1 = new MyClass({request: req1});
const c2 = new MyClass({request: req2});

// As expected
c1.request();
c2.request();
console.log('---');

// As expected
c1.foo();
c2.foo();
console.log('---');

// Error: both call req1
c1.actions.foo();
c2.actions.foo();
console.log('---');
```

I may not have covered all edge cases there, and you'll have to decide whether to cater for (say) RegExp or Date objects, etc.

Comment: Wow, thank you! I will need some time to understand this. But I still can not understand why `actions` object become shared. I thought it will become shared ONLY between created instance and temporary object (e.g. {request: req1}) in constructor's args. And the same for the seconds instance, but now between them all. Maybe I still do not know something about constructors...

Comment: @saintcrawler: It's not to do with constructors, it's because when you do `this[k] = obj[k];`, you share the original `actions` object you passed to `createClass` with the instance and then you modify it. So all the instances are using the same object. That's why the suggestion above fixes it, because we use `this[k] = Object.assign({}, obj[k]);` to *copy* the object so the instance gets its own, before we modify it.

Comment: But all instances, created by the class which is returned from `createClass` _should_ share same `actions` object. This is what I want to get. For example, same `actions.foo` function for all instances, but `this.request()` inside `foo` should invoke their own `request` function. In other words all functions in `actions` object should be in prototype of the class, but should be invoked with correct instance's `this`. I am new to javascript and maybe there is another, better solution to this problem.

Comment: @saintcrawler: They can't all share the same `actions` object if you do your loop over that object binding the functions that are on it to the last instance created.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Seems like a tricky one to understand, when `const c1 = new MyClass({request: req1});` this line got executed, the c1.actions.foo would be bound with c1, and c1.request() will print "req1 called". That is perfectly fine. And after that,  when this line `const c2 = new MyClass({request: req2});` got executed c2.actions.foo would be bound with c2 because of this line `...this.actions[k] = this.actions[k].bind(this)..` and calling it should print "req2 called". I understand that both are sharing same actions but why req2 is not getting updated?? Can you please help me to understand?

Comment: As per my understanding, after the execution of these two lines `const c1 = new MyClass({request: req1}); const c2 = new MyClass({request: req2});` ,  `c1.actions.foo()` and `c2.actions.foo()` has to print `req2 called`. Because the sharing object's function(actions.foo) has been bound with c2. But it is printing `req1 called` in both ways. why is so?? Its really difficult to understand for me.

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy: It's complicated, the binding on a central object really creates a lot of cross-talk. `req2.request()` calls the function assigned to the `request` property of `req2`. The second of the OP's `Object.keys().forEach` loops ensures that that property refers to a function bound to `req2`, so we see `"req2"`. But the call to `req2.actions.foo()` calls the `foo` on `actions`, which is bound to `req1`; within the call, `this` refers to the *first* instance created. So `this.request()` outputs `"req1"`.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder _"The bind() function creates a new function (a bound function) with the same function body (internal call property in ECMAScript 5 terms) as the function it is being called on (the bound function's target function) with the this value bound to the first argument of bind(), which cannot be overridden."_ Hi TJ, I found this statement in official doc. And it helped me to solve the mystery. You are [always](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35794914/mysterious-behaviour-of-closure-inside-a-constructor) helping me in solving mysteries. :) :) Thank you very much. :)